# Bash - waiting on child processes, differences between loop types

Tags: multithreading, bash, sleep

The below script contains two loops that fork processes to the background. They behave differently in that the `for` loop produces the expected results (waits for 10 child processes to complete) however the `while` loop does not produce the same results. Based on the output of `pstree`, it is clear that the `while` loop does not cause the child processes to be children of the current shell. I suspect this is due to the pipeline?

```
$ /tmp/wtf    
1499921102 - for loop - start
wtf(2797)─┬─pstree(2810)
          ├─sleep(2800)
          ├─sleep(2801)
          ├─sleep(2802)
          ├─sleep(2803)
          ├─sleep(2804)
          ├─sleep(2805)
          ├─sleep(2806)
          ├─sleep(2807)
          ├─sleep(2808)
          └─sleep(2809)
1499921102 - for loop - waiting
1499921112 - for loop - done
1499921112 - while loop - start
wtf(2797)───pstree(2826)
1499921112 - while loop - waiting
1499921112 - while loop - done


$ cat /tmp/wtf 
#!/bin/bash

set -m
set -e 
set -u

printf "%s - for loop - start\n" "$(date +%s)"
for i in `seq 1 10`
do
  sleep 10 &
done
pstree -pl $$
printf "%s - for loop - waiting\n" "$(date +%s)"
wait
printf "%s - for loop - done\n" "$(date +%s)"

printf "%s - while loop - start\n" "$(date +%s)"
seq 1 10 | while read i
do
  sleep 10 &
done 
pstree -pl $$ 
printf "%s - while loop - waiting\n" "$(date +%s)" 
wait
printf "%s - while loop - done\n" "$(date +%s)"
```

How might I get the current process to wait on processes that are not direct children? An attempt to pass the process ids into `wait` was not successful:

```
wait $(seq 1 10 | while read i
do
  sleep 10 &
  echo $!
done | tr '\n' ' ')

/tmp/wtf: line 22: wait: pid 2866 is not a child of this shell
/tmp/wtf: line 22: wait: pid 2867 is not a child of this shell
/tmp/wtf: line 22: wait: pid 2868 is not a child of this shell
/tmp/wtf: line 22: wait: pid 2869 is not a child of this shell
/tmp/wtf: line 22: wait: pid 2870 is not a child of this shell
/tmp/wtf: line 22: wait: pid 2871 is not a child of this shell
/tmp/wtf: line 22: wait: pid 2872 is not a child of this shell
/tmp/wtf: line 22: wait: pid 2873 is not a child of this shell
/tmp/wtf: line 22: wait: pid 2874 is not a child of this shell
/tmp/wtf: line 22: wait: pid 2875 is not a child of this shell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research I confirmed my suspicion that the loop inside of a pipeline creates a subshell. What I learned is that `wait` will only wait for children of the current shell, so the cleanest solution I could think of was to ensure the backgrounded tasks and the wait are in the same subshell. I achieved this by wrapping the loop and the `wait` in a set of curly-braces inside the pipeline.

```
printf "%s - while loop - start\n" "$(date +%s)"
seq 1 10 | {
  while read i
  do
    sleep 10 &
  done 
  pstree -pl $$ 
  printf "%s - while loop - waiting\n" "$(date +%s)" 
  wait
}
printf "%s - while loop - done\n" "$(date +%s)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Some experiments...

This `while`-based version seems to work:

```
seq 1 10 | while read i; do sleep 10 &  echo $!; done | xargs sh -c wait
```

This also works:

```
sh -c wait $(seq 1 10 | while read i; do sleep 10 &  echo $!; done)
```

Notes:

- The `tr` is needless.
- Since `wait` is a shell builtin command, `xargs` can't see it without
  the `sh -c`.
- Evidently the `sh -c` is necessary, (even without `xargs`), so it's a *builtin* problem...